# Trying to declare a variable in dockerfile but not working: AZ_REPO=$('lsb_release -cs')

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-cli

I have this commands, if I do them inside interactive terminal of docker container it works and `$AZ_REPO` is assigned a value:

```
AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

Now if I put this in my Dockerfile `$AZ_REPO` then gets no value assigned to it:

```
RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
RUN echo $AZ_REPO // this prints nothing
```

I tried using ARG but it doesn't work:

```
ARG AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
```

my container seed is using `FROM node:lts-slim`

Comment: Anything you set in a `RUN` command will get reset at the end of that command (so you could `RUN AZ_REPO=$(...); echo $AZ_REPO` in a single command, but not split across multiple `RUN` lines).  There's no Docker syntax to persistently set an `ENV` variable based on a command output.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze, due to your answer got this working with command `RUN AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list`